# How to share webhook code and intents works together?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I' m working with dialogflow to have a chatbot for renting different buildings(in my case called FMRs). I have a "New FMR" intent as shown in the following picture:
[image: FMR.png]

As you see this FMR has different rent prices according to its facilities.I have a graphql database to store FMRs and their parameters. I used webhook and wrote a piece of java script code to get the list of FMRs. Whenever user says "Set up a new FMR called TEST with rent two bedroom at $1500" my code checks whether the FMR name(TEST) exists in the database or not.If it exists we should ask the user if she/he wants to edit the parameters of existed FMR, and if it doesn't exist, the new FMR will be created in database. My problem is with the first part that FMR exists in database.As I only can check its existence in my own code, where can I ask the user to edit the existed FMR or no and get his/her response to continue the work? How can I have a sub-intent to connect it to my code and have the above scenario correctly? Or how can I trigger a sub-intent in my code to be executed after user says "Yes" or "no" to my question about "editing existed FMR"? Sorry for long description and thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'm a little confused about how you want the conversation flow to work. Ignoring how to implement it - what should the possible conversations look like?

Comment: The conversations should be something like this:  client:"set up a new FMR under fmr mountain view with rents, studio at $1000, one bedroom at $1200, two bedroom rented at $1400, three bedroom priced at $1600 and four bedroom at $1800.  bot:"The mountain view FMR exists,do you want to edit it?"  client:"No"  bot:"Ok,please enter new FMR name"  or  client:"Yes, I want to edit"  bot:"Please enter the properties you want to edit"

Comment: And if the FMR doesn't exist? (And it is generally better to update the original question rather than try to answer things in the comments.)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.But I mentioned them in the main question. This part is from my original question => "Whenever user says "Set up a new FMR called TEST with rent two bedroom at $1500" my code checks whether the FMR name(TEST) exists in the database or not.If it exists we should ask the user if she/he wants to edit the parameters of existed FMR, and if it doesn't exist, the new FMR will be created in database". If you think the original question needs more update please let me know.

Comment: Would you please help me on this?I really need some solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still confused about how this conversation flow should look, but it sounds like it would be something like this:

- User Says: "Create a new FMR named *name* with..."

  If "name" does not exist, save the data, reply with "The FMR named *name* has been created" and close the conversation.

  If "name" exists, reply: "The *name* FMR exists. Do you want to edit it?"

  - User says: "no"

    Reply: "What should it be named?"

    User says the new name and processing repeats as above.
  - User says: "yes"

    Save the data, reply with "The FMR named *name* has been updated", and close the conversation.

In your fulfillment code, if you need to ask the yes/no question, you'd also reply with a [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts), setting the parameters with enough information so you can remember what the user has already said about this FMR the next time your fulfillment gets called.

You can then create [followup Intents](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#follow_up_intents) for the "Yes" and "No" responses. Give each one a different Action setting, so you can differentiate them in your fulfillment. You'll also need another Intent that has this Context as the input context and has sample phrases that match how the user will specify the name (ie - with a parameter named "fmr-name" of type @sys.any) - this can have the same Action setting as your original Intent.

When your fulfillment is called again, you know if they've responded yes or no (by checking the Action). If they've said "yes", you have the previous information they already said and can save and exit.

If they've said "no", you'll prompt for the new name and set the Context again with the information you need to remember when you get a reply. When they do reply, you'll check the parameters for the new name and use the values from the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes, you got my problem right. But as I set the webhook reply in my back end code as : *webhookReply = "This FMR exists. Do you want to edit it?"* and shows this reply to user with : *res.status(200).json({
    source: 'webhook',
    speech: webhookReply,
    displayText: webhookReply
  })* in my javascript back end code, I want to know that after asking this question, how should I get "yes" or " no" from user in my code and call and execute proper intent.Does "event" part of intent do this? Do you have any example of this to show me?

Comment: There was an error in my second link. It should have been a followup Intent. See if that documentation (and the documentation about Contexts) helps you.