# How can I trigger a dialogflow intent inside a javascript code?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a chatbot using dialogflow agent. I wrote a javascript back end code for its webhook fulfillment. I checked some condition in this code and if the condition is true I want a special intent to be triggered. How can I do this? What is the correct java script code to triggered an intent inside a java script if statement?

Comment: Can you update your question to explain this a little clearer? Inside your fulfillment, you want to trigger a different intent and the fulfillment for that one? (What is the data flow you're picturing here?)

Comment: At first I explained it with details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48773305/how-to-share-webhook-code-and-intents-works-together) ,but no body answered it.

Comment: Asking the question a second time is frowned upon by StackOverflow. Asking it a second time with *fewer* details than the first time doesn't seem like a wise way to get an answer if you didn't the first time.

Comment: Does this actually have to trigger the intent in dialogflow or is executing the code from a different intent in the webhook based on the if statement the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

What function do you intend to perform by triggering an intent? Diaglogflow has `v1 & v2 API references` for this. You can do `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE` operations by triggering an intent using ajax call in your javascript code. Please read more about this here https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/intents

Comment: The documentation you referenced to only discusses the creation and deletion of intents, not **triggering** them as the OP asked

Answer (score 0):

To make things clearer, DialogFlow intents are triggered by querying using the query API (https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/query)

*Note: V1 of the DialogFlow API will deprecate soon, and will be replaced by V2 which is using gRPC.*

This means that if you wish to trigger the intent programmatically and have the fulfilment triggered as well, you should have the following:

1. Script (can be on JavaScript as you would like to) with REST API request (doable using the `Axios` library) to the DialogFlow Query API.
2. DialogFlow will pick up the query, runs it through and triggers the Intent (if the query matches the intent).
3. In processing the intent, because there is a fulfilment, DialogFlow will run the fulfilment, which is another API/webhook call to your server hosted somewhere.
4. Your server will pick up the API request, and process accordingly.

Try out the Query API from DialogFlow and see if it works out for you.

Comment: this requires a sessionId which is only active for 20 mins; therefore you wouldn't be able to trigger an intent for an arbitrary user

Comment: You can specify a session id yourself, it doesn't have to be generated by dialogflow iirc. Just put something like 1234 should work I think.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am late here, but I have used the below approach to encounter such a situation.
You can use **custom event** and **intent chaining**.

I followed the below URL and implemented the same. Maybe this help someone.

[enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/events-custom)